# float value is rounded off after commitchanges

Tags: pyqgis

Getting field value rounded off to integer equivalent after commiting changes to layer

```
layer.startEditing()
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(_NEW_AET, QVariant.Double,'double', 3, 4)])
    layer.updateFields()

    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        if(f[_NEW_LU] == 'agriculture' or f[_NEW_LU] == 'fallow land'):
            print sht_op.range('Q185').value - 0.0
            f[_NEW_AET] = sht_op.range('Q185').value - 0.0
            print f[_NEW_AET]
            layer.updateFeature(f)
        break
    layer.commitChanges()

    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        print f[_NEW_AET]
        break
```

For above code getting output rounded off after commitChanges() to layer

Below is the output:

```
359.801528696
359.801528696
359.0
```

Comment: That's what you asked for with 3,4 - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174971/how-to-define-the-number-of-decimals-when-adding-a-new-field-as-double-to-an-att