# Exporting coordinates to CSV with 2 decimals using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to export a point-layer to a CSV using a plugin I am working on. Amongst other attributes, the coordinates are exported via `layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XY']`. Everything is working fine, however, I need the coordinates with only 2 decimals instead of the standard 10 for further processing in LaTeX.

Here's a minimum example of my code:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layerPKT, QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")+'/KVZ_NEU.csv', "utf-8", layer.crs(), "CSV", True, layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XY'])
```

This is the output I get:

```
X,Y,PNR,KG,IND,GFN,KLASSIFIZI,BEVTYP
31490.0792899652,181684.344823149,"1","75314",,,n,GP
```

And this is the output I want:

```
X,Y,PNR,KG,IND,GFN,KLASSIFIZI,BEVTYP
31490.08,181684.34,"1","75314",,,n,GP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little workaround for my problem:

I created two new attributes `X` and `Y` for the layer and set the length and precision as posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174971/how-to-define-the-number-of-decimals-when-adding-a-new-field-as-double-to-an-att).

Then I used a QGIS Expression `$x` and `$y` in order to populate the new fields.